# How to create a pre-packaged deployment script for a database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssms

I have a DB project in Visual Studio and I need to deploy it to a remote system as a pre-packaged script (or similar) as a new database.

The **Publish** option will generate a .publish SQL script but only if you supply a connection first, and the script includes machine-local information e.g. logging paths.

I want something I can copy onto the DB-server machine running SSMS and it will create the DB. What is the proper way to do this, I see I also have DAC and DLL files emitted during build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way to do this?

Connect to a server that doesn't have any version of your database, and publish.  Publish calculates an *incremental* deployment, so it needs to see the current state of the target SQL Server.

Comment: I cannot connect to the server. I need to produce something I can transfer to a separate system. It doesn't have to be SQL scripts but that's all I'm familiar with. Is that what all this DAC/DLLs are for?

Comment: Publish to a local SQL Server to generate the script.

Comment: Sorry I misread you there that makes more sense.